# psql date_trunc issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query in my psql database but I have a slight problem:

```
select sge_job.j_id,
       sge_job_usage.ju_id,
       sge_job_usage.ju_slots,
       date_trunc ('hour',sge_job_usage.ju_start_time) – date_trunc ('hour',sge_job.j_submission_time) as "Wait time"
from sge_job,
     sge_job_usage
where sge_job.j_id = sge_job_usage.ju_id
and   sge_job_usage.ju_start_time >= sge_job.j_submission_time
```

The problem is the information I get for my ju_start_time and j_submission_time will leave it within the hour format but some of them will have information thats 3 days 12hours for example.

They are both timestamp without timezone but I need it to calculate if it's 2 days and add them into hours. so my current out put is:

```
71 |    71 |        1 | 01:00:00
72 |    72 |        1 | 01:00:00
73 |    73 |        2 | 4 days 03:00:00
74 |    74 |        2 | 01:00:00
75 |    75 |        2 | 03:00:00
76 |    76 |        2 | 03:00:00
77 |    77 |        1 | 22:00:00
78 |    78 |        1 | 18:00:00
79 |    79 |        2 | 19:00:00
80 |    80 |        2 | 20:00:00
81 |    81 |        2 | 20:00:00
82 |    82 |        2 | 11:00:00
83 |    83 |        2 | 21:00:00
84 |    84 |        2 | 1 day 10:00:00
85 |    85 |        2 | 1 day 17:00:00
86 |    86 |        2 | 2 days 17:00:00
```

so with the date_trunc hour it changes my time format to how many hours, but I can't seem to get a function that will get rid of my days and put them into hour format so i would like 86's column to be 48 hours ( 2 days) + 17 = 65 hours as it's result, any suggestions what to try ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting a timestamp from another timestamp yields an interval value. You have to convert that interval to hours in order to get your display.

To convert an interval to e.g. hours, you use the following:

```
extract(epoch from <interval_value>) / 3600
```

`epoch` returns seconds. Dividing that value by 3600 gives you hours.

In your case, the following should do what you want:

```
extract(epoch from date_trunc('hour',sge_job_usage.ju_start_time) – date_trunc ('hour',sge_job.j_submission_time)) / 3600 as "Wait time"
```

Comment: thankyou very much for that, work's exactly how I need it to now